# In Sierra, did Apple remove the ability to play HLS streams in Quicktime Player?

Tags: macos, quicktime, streaming

For years, I've been able to use Quicktime to play live HLS video streams such as http://hls.twit.tv/flosoft/mp4:twitStream_720/playlist.m3u8. I open Quicktime, go to File -> Open Location, and paste the URL.

After upgrading to Sierra, streams such as the above example no longer play.

Did Apple remove this feature in Sierra, or is there something else I'm doing wrong? Are there any types of live streams that Quicktime still natively supports? Is this just a bug that's likely to get fixed? I can't find actual documentation on this anywhere.

Comment: I don't think so. https://developer.apple.com/streaming/ What about in web browsers, does that also not work for you?

Comment: Works fine in Safari once I enable the plugin. Works fine on my iPhone too.

Comment: It works for me. I have macOS Sierra 10.12 Beta (16A313a). QuickTime plays the video (right now it shows something about kickstarter).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have macOS Sierra 10.12 Beta (16A313a) and it seems, that Apple has fixed the issue.

I can't find release notes or something like this to point on exact QuickTime version, where this was fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Just tried here using your link with QuickTime player on latest Sierra 10.12.3, and video indeed does not play.

Strangely - I get the audio only. I tried to use HTTPS instead of HTTP, but then I got an error "cannot parse". from QuickTime

In VLC I see the stream immediately, so that rules out Firewall issues.

So for now, I confirm that QuickTime is broken for HLS playback.

Answer (score -2):

I didn't try QuickTime, but the URL you provided works fine with VLC:

1. http://www.videolan.org/vlc/
2. After installation, choose
   `File` -> `Open Network`
3. paste in your URL.